# Software Update Presuming to Upgrade My System to Ubuntu 12.10

Tags: 12.04, upgrade, updates, 12.10

I'm using Ubuntu 12.04 LTS, which I'm perfectly happy with.  The past week, Software Update has been pushing me (without my intervention) to upgrade to 12.10.  Rather than presenting me with the "Upgrade" button at the top of the Software Update dialog box, it just automatically selects a bunch of critical updates (C libraries, X & nVidia drivers, etc.) suitable for upgrades only, and warns me about having to update in two separate attempts ("Not all updates can be installed").

I don't want to do this!  I just want to make standard security and bug fixes and stick with 12.04.  (I unselected "recommended updates" to avoid the problem, but it seems to be a strange way to deal with this.)  Is there some setting I need to reset to avoid this behavior?  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Open **Update Manager** and go to Settings. Set **Show new distribution releases** to **Long term releases only**.

Click **Check** and any offer to upgrade things in within the normal 12.04 release cycle.